# Error: no such partition - when starting up my laptop

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning

When I start my laptop (dual boot, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20), I am getting a black screen that says "Error: no such partition. Press any key to continue". When I press the key, I am directed to the boot screen again where I have to select the OS. This is happening for both Ubuntu and Windows, and as far as I know I haven't had any hardware / software issues so far.

It doesn't make sense to be a problem with Ubuntu / Windows itself. I won't be able to find a repair shop for the next 24 hours, and I need to work with my ubuntu os, without erasing the code I worked for the past two days in it.

Could you give me a hand on what this could be or how to diagnose it? Currently I am using a bootable USB I had to be able to start. Other than that, I don't have any other means to deal with this situation.

This is a screenshot of the disk partition (from gparted). I don't know if it helps or what else I could provide.
[image]

Edit: The accepted answer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125428/grub-complains-of-no-such-partition-after-installing-1204) seemed to fix the issue. I'll wait a day or two before marking the post as duplicate. Thanks to @alecxs for pointing me the right direction.

Edit: The answer above fixed the issue - which means that I was able to log into ubuntu for the next days. However, I cannot mark it as duplicate since the posts are on different communities. Also, today I had another issue during boot, although it was a different kind of prompt that required another aproach. So I suspect that in my specific case I should investigate deeper on what is going on with my partitions.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=grub+rescue

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to report outcome, +1

Comment: i have had this behavior on my old PC, but funny thing was it "fixed" itself on the next day. some days later again.. turned out it was weak hard disk starting slowly to die